# FAB to show in every activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a Floating Action Button  that will show in every activity that is being ran. How would I accomplish to get the layout to show in each activity.

I have seen some methods with WindowManager but I am not a fan of it sitting on top of the app and needing the overlay aspect to it. Is there a better way with ZIndex or adding to the view from a service when a new activity is transitioned, etc. to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate class with a static method, which will create a FabButton and will attach it to your root view.

```
    public class FabButton {
      public static void init(AppCompatActivity activity){
        View root = root.getWindow().getDecorView();
        FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(getContext());
        fab.setId(R.id.fab);
        fab.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ));
        root.addView(fab);
      }
    }
```

And you can use this wherever you want to add. In your activity's `onCreate`, call:

```
FabButton.init(this);
```

Edit: I found a better answer according to your requirement

in your application class'`onCreate`, add

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
```

And then implement methods of `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`.

Now in

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   FabButton.init(activity);
 }
```

Comment: I believe to get the method addView. You need to have param ViewGroup in the param. Also do you think I would be able to set this init in a `onCreate` method that extends the application? Would this keep it active during the whole app?

Comment: No, not in the application class. That needs to be called in each activity. It is just an easier and cleaner approach.

Comment: I understand but I want to make something that doesn't need to be called every activity. Is their a way to do it on the application level so that when the action is init; its init on all activities?

Comment: Application class is called before the first activity is created. For global initialization, etc. Fab Button can be added to activity only after it has been created. So either create a superclass for each activity or something that I suggested.

Comment: Thanks. You can select one of the answers as correct if it helped.

Comment: @codegeek123 i think it is impossible to change all layouts in application class. but it may be possible to change all layouts as part of building process (before apk is created) if you can create a gradle plugin

Comment: Mukarram to access the addView method you must work within the viewgroup?

Comment: @codegeek123 dude, check my updated answer. Now you can do this from your Application class only.

Answer (score 1):

create a layout `fab_layout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:backgroundTint="#00ff00"/>
```

in all activities add this tag:

```
<include layout="@layout/fab_layout />
```

Comment: Like I am thinking to possibly make a library that can just maybe set the layout at runtime on top of the app from the application level. But is this possible?

Comment: This will make the UI look different, it won be smooth , like when changing from one activity to another we will we seeing 2 FAB it will be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base activity "FABActivity" in which you can add the FAB button to the root layout at runtime in the onCreate() method.

Every activity which extends this activity will have the same FAB this way.

Comment: Yea. I saw this way to do it. But I want to be able to do it in abetter way without having to extend from another activity. Like I am thinking to possibly make a library that can just maybe set the layout at runtime on top of the app from the application level. But is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad of ways said here that you can achieve what you want.

Here is another one:

You can have all your activities as fragments. You can create one MainActivity with xml layout with Relative layout in which you will add your FAB there and a container(with width and height=`match_parent` for the fragments(your activities).